# How to remove unwanted space between these two DIVs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two div with 100 % width I have problem I am getting space between div I am using bootstrap and tried different CSS properties but nothing happens
I want 0 margin between them can't figure it out how its can be done

[image]

My Code:

```css
          .sec-one {
            height: 200px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: pink;
          }
          .sec-two {
            height: 200px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: red;
            text-align: center;
          }
          #header h1 a {
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 1.8em;
            color: white;
            margin-top: 90px;
          }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="sec-one">

  </div>

  <div class="sec-two">

    <div id="header">
      <h1><strong><a href="">A Heading</a></strong></h1>
    </div>

  </div>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The problem is the margin that bootstrap applies to `h1`. You need to reset it. See Antonio's answer... http://stackoverflow.com/a/33938050/3170478

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just insert `h1 {margin:0px}` in your stylesheet and it will work.

In my example the property is sitting at the top.

[**Example**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/YyoQLK?editors=110)

Comment: Thanks alot @Antonio Smoljan

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
.sec-one {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:pink;
  }

  .sec-two{
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:red;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #header h1 a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 90px;
  }
h1
{
    margin:0;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="sec-one">

  </div>

  <div class="sec-two">

    <div id="header">
      <h1><strong><a href="">A Heading</a></strong></h1>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h1 {font-size:0px} //it will also work in case display:inline-block of div's
```

Comment: Thanks for Your Answer Sir